# Regarding notation, for $f(x,y)$ are $f_x(x,g(x))$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,g(x))$ interpreted differently?

Tags: notation

More specifically, I see $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,g(x))$ as meaning take the derivative of $f(x,g(x))$ w.r.t $x$.

On the other hand, I see $f_x(x,g(x))$ as meaning the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ **evaluated at $(x,g(x))$**

> Do these notations have clearly defined meanings -- i.e. is it clear whether we take the derivative and then evaluate or evaluate and then take the derivative -- or does it depend on context?
>
> If they do not, how can I be clear in which order to take the derivative and evaluate?

---

As an illustration, consider $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$

Then $f_x(x,y) = 2x$

I would then say that $f_x(x,g(x))= 2x$

Whereas I would say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,g(x)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2 + g(x)^2 \right)= 2x + 2g(x)g'(x) = f_x(x,g(x) )+f_y(g(x))g'(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish between $\frac d {dx}$ and $\frac {\partial} {\partial x}$. Your calculation of $\frac {\partial} {\partial x} f (x,g(x))$ is wrong and you have to intepret it as $f_x$ evaluated at $(x,g(x))$.

Comment: How is my calculation for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,(g(x)))$ wrong? And how is the distinguish between $\frac{d}{dx}$ and the partial form relevant here, given that $f(x,g(x))$ is only a function of $x$, so $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ would give the same thing?

Comment: It is a question of conventions. In the expression $\frac {\partial} {\partial x} f (x,g(x))$ you are suppose to club $\frac {\partial} {\partial x}$ and $f$ together and $(x,g(x))$ comes later.

Comment: Is there a way to say $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of $f(x,g(x))$? Maybe define $z(x)=f(x,g(x))$ and write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} z(x)$?

Comment: @user106860 For the derivative of $f(x,g(x))$ w.r.t. $x$ we always use $\frac d {dx}$ and do not use the symbols $\partial$.